# How to intercept multiple Redux toolkit Createapi

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am using this solution https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery to write reAuth baseQuery.

However I have multiple backend services with different createAPI services consume same refresh token concept.

Is there any way to have one baseQueryAuth can be used for multiple createApis

for example

productQuery.tsx

```
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
     // reset token
  }
  return result
}
/** Product Query **/
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_PRODUCT_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const productAPI = createApi({
   reducerPath: 'productAPI',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    ...
    ...
    }
   })
```

On customerQuery.tsx

```
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
  string | FetchArgs,
  unknown,
  FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
     // reset token
  }
  return result
}
/** Customer Query **/
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const customerAPI = createApi({
   reducerPath: 'customerAPI',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    ...
    ...
    }
   })
```

Is there any way I can move the baseQueryWithReauth outside as one function and pass/bind the baseQuery based on different API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can create a higher order function with [currying](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-javascript-currying), `baseQueryWithReauth` will be a function that receives a baseQuery function as an argument and returns another baseQuery function

```
import { fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
...

type BaseQueryType = ReturnType<typeof fetchBaseQuery>;

const baseQueryWithReauth: (baseQuery: BaseQueryType) => BaseQueryType = (
  baseQuery
) => async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
     // reset token
  }
  return result
}
```

and then use it to build each API

```
const productBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_PRODUCT_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const productAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: "customerAPI",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth(productBaseQuery),
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    ...
  },
});
```

```
const customerBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_URL,
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    return headers;
  },
});

const customerAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: "customerAPI",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth(customerBaseQuery),
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    ...
  },
});
```

here is a sandbox for reference

https://codesandbox.io/s/hof-redux-toolkit-api-dlel1g?file=/src/api.ts

Comment: I would rather pass only baseUrl

Comment: I tried this initially, however this throws error on typescript as Argument of type 'EndpointBuilder<BaseQueryFn<any, unknown, unknown, {}, {}>, is not assignable to parameter of type EndpointBuilder<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>,'

Comment: @kishorekumaru sorry I was lazy about the typing, I updated my answer including types, do let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes @diedu that works `type BaseQueryType = ReturnType<typeof fetchBaseQuery>` and `(baseQuery: BaseQueryType) => BaseQueryType = (baseQuery) =>` made that trick. I was running on a different direction

Comment: Is it possible to curry the createApi function? Because I want to abstract other props such as extractRehydrationInfo for usage with redux-persist and have to botther adding it for each createSlice instance.